# variable used before declaration

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I generated my project using angular-cli which version is `1.0.0-beta.28.3`.
I write in the terminal a command `ng lint` and get big amount errors:

[image]

I haven't any ideas why I get such amount errors after running `ng lint` .

Below code of `machines.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DialogService } from 'ng2-bootstrap-modal';

import { ModalComponent } from '../modal/modal.component';
import { MachineService } from '../services/machine.service';
import { Machine } from '../models/machine.model';
import { BoxService } from '../services/box.service';
import { Box } from '../models/box.model';
import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-machines',
  templateUrl: './machines.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./machines.component.scss']
})
export class MachinesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private display: boolean;
  private alive: boolean;
  private timer: Observable<number>;
  machines: Machine [];
  box: Box;

  constructor(
    private dialogService: DialogService,
    private boxService: BoxService,
    private machineService: MachineService,
    private appConfig: AppConfig) {
    this.display = false;
    this.alive = true;
    this.timer = Observable.timer(0, this.appConfig.interval_requests);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.timer
      .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.machineService.getStatesMachines().subscribe(
          (res: Response) => {
            this.machines = res.json();

            if (!this.display) {
              this.display = true;
            }
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.alive = false;
  }

  getBox(device_name: string) {
    this.boxService.getBox(device_name).subscribe(
      (res: Response) => {
        const box = res.json();
        this.box = box;

        this.dialogService.addDialog(ModalComponent, {
          device_name: this.box.device_name + '`s info',
          name: this.box.name,
          timestamp: this.box.timestamp,
          ip_address: this.box.ip_address
        }, {closeByClickingOutside: true});
      }
    );
  }

}
```

When project was generated I didn't change any properties in `tslint.json`. Default, `"no-use-before-declare": true`.

I searched the answers at Github and at Stackoverflow, but didn't find. Perhaps, I searched it badly if so far didn't find.
 Please, help me.

Comment: Why don't you start by upgrading to the latest stable version of ng-cli, and the version of tslint that comes with it. There are probably a whole lot of bugs and improvements that have been brought since the obsolete beta version you're using.

Comment: I updated `angular-cli`.

Answer (score 4):

you can set `"no-use-before-declare": false`

This rule is primarily useful when using the `var` keyword - the compiler will detect if a `let` and `const` variable is used before it is declared

Comment: I had wanted to set `"no-use-before-declare": false`, but, finally, I decided that better ability if I am updating a version `angular-cli`.